# Load/access/mount directory to aws sagemaker from S3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

I am a newbee to aws s3/sagemaker. I am strugling to access my data [data meaning folders/directories, not any specific file/files] from S3 bucket to sagemaker jupyter notebook.

Say, my URI is:

`s3://data/sub/dir/`, where `dir` may contain multiple directories with files. I need to acess the directory (e.g., dir) in such a way where I can access any sub directories/files from it. I tried-

`!aws s3 cp s3://data/sub/dir tempdata --recursive` but did not work, getting error like-

`fatal error: An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Key "sub/dir" does not exist`.

Please advice, how can I access the dirs from s3 buckets to my aws sagemaker jupyter lab.

Or how to mount s3 buckets to sagemaker? I also tried [this link](https://medium.com/tensult/aws-how-to-mount-s3-bucket-using-iam-role-on-ec2-linux-instance-ad2afd4513ef) and installed with no errors but s3fs wont show when I run `dh -f`, thus not worked as well! Thanks in advance.

Comment: `aws s3 cp s3://data/sub/dir tempdata --recursive` is perfectly valid - does `data/sub/dir` actually exist and have "files" underneath it?

Comment: Yes, there are data. one more thing, the error returns ```sub/dir``` not the whole path like ```data/sub/dir/```. is it suppse to be or there is something wrong? do you have any other suggestions, please? @ErmiyaEskandary

Comment: Can you please update the question with the exact output of `aws s3 cp s3://data/sub/dir tempdata --recursive` given that `data` is your bucket name and `sub/dir` the path?

Comment: this is the exact error I am getting ```fatal error: An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Key "sub/dir" does not exist``` @ErmiyaEskandary

Comment: Can you show me the hierarchy of sub/dir from the console, please? It doesn't look like sub/dir exists (considering you're replacing them with the correct values) - the path is wrong

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I actually got it (```aws s3 cp```) working. I created a whole new instance and got to work. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1):

Your `cp` syntax is correct.
S3 `Sync` could be an alternative way to get the same result, and the error response, if you got something wrong, could be more informative: `!aws s3 sync s3://data/sub/dir tempdata`